# WPF - what is the best way to bind data from a database to a checkbox control

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I am struggling some time with checkbox control in WPF. What I am trying is to to make some kind of filter.
1. So first I need to fill the checkbox control with the database items
2. Second I need to check if anything is checked
3. Third if anything is checked I want to take those values and use them to search through the database
4. Should I use only checkbox control for this or should I put it in some container or a listBox?

I have find many topics here that are mentioning this stuff, but I couldn't manage to find the complete answer, only lot of parts that are not compatible with each other. I would really appreciate if someone explain to me how checkbox in WPF works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple values and you want to display multiple CheckBoxes, one for each of them, then you will need to use a ListBox and have the TemplateItem a CheckBox. This way your collection of items is bound to the ListBox, and for each item in the ListBox a CheckBox is shown.

So to get each of the values after there is an additional step if your doing MVVM and don't want to touch the UI. What you do is create a wrapper class that sits around your class and has a extra property for the IsChecked data. This way you can get the checked state without touching the UI.

I have an example of this on my blog: 
[Checked ListBox in WPF](http://www.jarloo.com/how-to-create-a-checkedlistbox-in-wpf/)

To check which items are checked you just need a simple LINQ query. So if you use the example there from my blog then you should be able to do something like this:

var checkedCustomers = Customers.Where(w=>w.IsChecked).ToList();

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kelly. I have used your code from the blog and when I started my application it didn't filled checkbox items at all, my listbox is empty. Also I noticed that you fill your Observable collection manually, is there a way you can fill it with data from the database so it will change automatically when data is changed in database?